# Android: Exit the app during splash screen if back or menu button is pressed?

Tags: android, splash-screen

Here is the source code. It's a basic splash screen, I want to finish this activity if the `back` or `menu` button is pressed.

```
try {
  super.run();
  /**
  * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
  * the wait variable for every 100L.
  */
  while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
    sleep(100);
    wait += 100;
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
} finally {
  /**
  * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
  * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
  */
  startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
  StartActivity.class));
  finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onBackPressed();
                finish();

    }
```

Use above method to finish  activity. 
This is one of the override method to close the activity while back or menu button is pressed

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but where should I place this?

Comment: you can place it anywhere inside the activity my friend

Answer (score 0):

Do the below in your splash screen class,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Here's an example with an animation for the Splash Screen, I initialize a new thread that wait for the animation before launching the next activity, I use the synchronized especially if I want to stop it as you can see it in the onTouchEvent and onKeyDown method.

```
  image.startAnimation(a);
            timer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(6500); // wait 6.5sec (animation time)
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
// After the 6.5 sec, start the new activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.start();

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (timer) {
        timer.notifyAll();
    }
    sound.release();
    finish();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        synchronized (timer) {
            timer.notifyAll();
        }
        sound.release();
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope it helps !